# Compare dictionary values against all other values in the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the format `D = {a:[x1,y1], b[x2,y2],.....}`

I have written a function to compare `[x1,y1]` with `[x2,y2]` such that:

```
 CompareVal([x1, y1], [x2, y2]):
    if (x2 > x1) and (y2 < y1):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

I need to iterate through the entire dictionary comparing the values of every key against all other keys, saving the total number of times the `return 1` is triggered. The end result is a list of lists `((a,n),(b,m)...)`, so that each key has the number of times the `return 1` was triggered.
It is important that `a` is compared to `b`, AND that `b` is compared to `a`.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: *'a' is compared to 'b'* - dict is unordered structure, you can't rely on consecutive comparison

Comment: Why do you need to have the result in a list of lists? What about having a dictionary `D_result` with keys equal to the keys from `D`, where the value of each key in `D_result` will be equal to its total score after comparing it to all other keys in `D`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension alone can do this with a double for:

```
def compare_values(p1, p2):
    if (p1[0] < p2[0]) and (p2[1] < p1[1]):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

a = { 'a': [0,60], 'b': [10,110], 'c':[20,100], 'd':[15,55], 'e':[12,108] }
output = [ (jk,sum([compare_values(jv, iv) for ik, iv in a.items() if ik != jk])) for jk, jv in a.items()]

print(output)
```

Using a test dictionary

```
a = { 'a': [2,40], 'b': [4,5], 'c':[5,4], 'd':[40,2] }
```

you get this output

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('d', 0)]
```

Comment: Using `a = { 'a': [0,60], 'b': [10,110], 'c':[20,100], 'd':[15,55], 'e':[12,108] }
` i'm getting this result: `[('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 2)]`. Maybe the compare function is different? I use `def compare_values(p1, p2):
    if (p1[0] < p2[0]) and (p2[1] < p1[1]):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0`

Comment: I've updated with the full code. Since it produces the right result I'm assuming the logic is correct.

Comment: Using `{ 'b': [10,110], 'c':[20,100], 'd':[15,55], 'a': [0,60], 'e':[12,108] }` I get `[('b', 3), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('a', 1), ('e', 2)]`. Is that not correct? Are you looking to sort the list?

Comment: Realised my mistake, my file importer is not working correctly. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare each pair of keys in `D` using your function `CompareVal` and save the score of each key in `D` to a new dictionary `D_results` as follows:

```
    D_results = {}
    for key1 in D.keys():
        for key2 in D.keys():
            if not key1 == key2:
                key1_result = CompareVal(D[key1], D[key2])
                # if key1 is not in D_results, make existing_result equal to 0
                existing_result = D_results.get(key1, 0)
                D_results[key1] = existing_result + 1
```

Comment: how would you compare it to another dictionary?